# Unable to pass a value to external JS file using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

> code is in the snippet area trying to pass a value to a java script
>   file
>
> ```
>   i am trying to pass a value to a java script file using add event listener  
>   not getting any value in return.
>   code is in the snippet section of my question
> ```

```
var x = document.get Element By Id("button");
x.  add Event Listener("click", resolve);
var y = document. get Element By Id("x").value;
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
    function resolve()`enter code here`
    {if (y >= 20000)
            {alert("yes greater than 20000");
            } else { alert("no  good");
            }
            }
  this is my code
```

Comment: You appear to have random spaces everywhere (and also an `enter code here` ,likely from incorrect question formatting), which will throw a syntax error. `get Element By Id("button")` should be `getElementById("button")`, for example.

Comment: I entered the code with that syntax because I was unable to submit otherwise

Comment: Please have a look: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't valid JavaScript. I fixed it below:

```
var x = document.getElementById("button");
x.addEventListener("click", resolve);
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("x").value);
function resolve() {
    if (y >= 20000) {
        alert("yes greater than 20000");
    } else {
        alert("no good");
    }
}
```